# Returning from a field collection with Dynamic library

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic

we are developing a framework that through the one url, generate a query based on the mapped entities by entity framework.

We are using the Dynamic Library ( http://lcs3.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/CoreTechnologies/CSharp/samples/CSharpSamples/LinqSamples/DynamicQuery/Dynamic%20Expressions.html) and we are struggling to return to the fields of a relationship 1..N.

Example:

```
TB_PEOPLE > TB_PHONE
```

Based on this relationship, I need to accomplish the same idea of ​​following linq:

```
var sql = from p in context.SomeTable
          select new { 
             NAME = p.NAME, 
             PHONES = p.TB_PHONE.Select(ph => ph.PHONE)
          };
```

Since I'm not working with typing, we chose to use dynamic library because apparently allowed us the flexibility to manipulate strings to return.
Then following the same idea , we set up the following line:

```
var sql = context.SomeTable.Select("new (TB_PEOPLE.TB_PHONE.PHONE)");
```

In this case , the returns an error stating that the attribute "PHONE" does not exist "TB_PEOPLE" of course ! So much so that we try to say that this attribute belongs to the table "TB_PHONE" but he does not understand.

So I ask you, how do I return to only certain fields of an entity where the relationship can be N? Also tried to call the method "Select":

```
var sql = context.SomeTable.Select("new (TB_PEOPLE.TB_PHONE.Select(PHONE))");
```

...there but I am informed that this method can not be used.

I do not know what else to do, any help will be appreciated!

Thank you.